# Simulate private interfaces in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, interface, interface-segregation-principle

I'm having an issue regarding the simulation of public interfaces in java 8.
I have this interface with this methods right now:

```
public interface A<T> {

    void method1(T t) throws someException;
    void method2(T t) throws someException;
    default method3() {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
}
```

The interface A is implemented by class `B`, which is an abstract class:

```
public abstract class B<T> implements A<T> {
    @Override
    public void method1(T type) throws someException {
        // (.... some code snipets ....)
    }
}
```

The `method1` contains all the logic and should be the one that the developer can see/use.

Now, bellow is represented the concrete representation of class `B`:

```
public final class ConcreteB extends B<someObject> {

    private static ConcreteB concreteBInstance = null;
    private ConcreteB() {
    }

    public static ConcreteB getInstance() {
        if (concreteBInstance == null) {
            concreteBInstance = new ConcreteB();
        }
        return concreteBInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void method2(someObject someObject) throws someException {
        //  (... code ...)
     }
}
```

So, to summarize, the concrete implementation of B implements the `method2` (and the method3, if the user wants to). The class B implements the `method1`, which contains all the logic.

My problem here is that when I do `ConcreteB.getInstance()`, the methods that are available for the developer to use are the `method1`, `method2`, and `method3`, and I want to make **only the method1 visible** to the developer. But because java 8 don't enable me to make private methods on interfaces, I don't know how to do it.

Any tips to how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the point of putting `method2` and `method3` into the interface at all, when nobody is supposed to call them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not put those "private" methods in the interface. An interface would force the public API of `B` and all its subclasses to expose all three methods to the world. That's because interfaces are designed to define a public API.

What you can do in this case is move all methods from the interface to `B`, except `method1`:

```
public interface A <T> {
    void method1(T t) throws someException;
}

public abstract class B<T> implements A<T> {

    protected abstract void method2(T t) throws someException;
    protected method3() {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void method1(T type) throws someException {
        (.... some code snipets ....)
    }
}
```

This way, you include in the public API only the methods you mean to include in it, and keep the rest only available to B and its subclasses. If the other two methods should not be accessible to subclasses of `B`, then you can make them private in `B`.

Further, if you want to prevent sub-classes of `B` from overriding `method1`, you can declare it as `final`.